# y'' + y = -sin(x)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'' + y = -\sin(x)$

$y(0) = 0 $

$y'(0) = 0$

I first solved for the homogeneous solution to get:

$y(x) = c_1 \sin(x) + c_2 \cos(x)$

then took the derivative of that:

$y'(x) = c_1 \cos (x) - c_2 \sin(x)$

This is where I am not sure where to go...

$y(0) = c_1 \sin(0) + c_2 \cos(0) 
     =  0 + c_2 $

so would c2 equal zero?

y'(0) = c1 cos(0) - c2 sin(0)
      =  c1 - 0

then c2 is zero too?

I don't think that's right, but I'm not sure what else to do. 
And where to go from there.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Laplace transform?  It would be convenient for your problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform

Comment: No, we haven't used that in class.

Comment: Try x cos x, you will have to divide later with 2 or something...

Comment: How about Taylor series: $y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} x^{n}$?  Compute the series for $y''(x)$, and write out the series for $\sin(x)$, and match the like powers.

Comment: Your solution *would* be correct if there equation was homogeneous (i.e., that pesky $\sin x$ term wasn't there.)  But you need to add in the particular solution as well before you apply the initial conditions.

Comment: The particular term (sinx) is also part of the homogenous solution, hence the linear factor of $x$ is needed, as laid out in the answer of Doug

Answer (score 1):

We must use the initial values for the general solution
$$y=c_1\sin x+c_2\cos x+y_p$$
the particular solution is
$$y_p=Ax\sin x+Bx\cos x$$
$$A=0,B=\frac{1}{2}$$
so the general solution is
$$y=c_1\sin x+c_2\cos x+\frac{x}{2}\cos x$$
now you can use the initial values to find the $A$ and $B$

Comment: For some reason the program that I am having to type the answers into is still saying these answers are wrong.

Comment: @Erica Firstly, I would like to know what's the name of the program you are using is reliable software?

Comment: Its called WeBWorks through MAA, its a mathematics program used by my university to assign homework problems. I try not to get help when doing them, but I am utterly stumped on this one.

Comment: @Erica Make sure the solution again and if you like to do a double check see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%2By%3D-sin+x

Answer (score 1):

$y'' + y = -\sin x$

solve the homogeneous equation

$y = c_1  \sin t + c_2 \cos x + y_p$

Undetermined coefficients.

$y = A x\sin x + Bx\cos x$

Why $A x \sin x + B x\cos x,$ and not the more simple-minded $A \sin x + B \cos x$?

$A \sin x + B \cos x$ is already part of the homogeneous solution.  So, when we plug it into the diff eq, it is going to "go away."  We need something that when differentiated (twice) has a part that equals $-\sin x$ but is not in the homogeneous solution.

$y' = A\sin x + B\cos x - B x\sin x + Ax\cos x\\
y'' = -2B \sin x + 2A\cos x - A x\sin x + Bx\cos x\\ 
y''+y = -2B \sin x + 2A\cos x = -\sin x\\
B = \frac 12, A = 0$

$y = c_1  \sin t + c_2 \cos x + \frac 12 x \cos x\\
y(0) = C_2 = 0\\
y'(0) = C_1 = 0$

$y = \frac 12  x\cos x$

Comment: There is a reason why the sine and cosine terms contain an $x$....That's crucial for your choice!